# How to integrate google map in my android auto app?

Tags: android, android-auto

I have android app with map, I am working on to add support of android auto to my existing android app.

I want integrate google map in android auto but Android car app library does not provide us the map with the templates, we'll need to use third party library to render map in android auto.

Can anyone please help to know or provide steps to integrate google map with android auto templates?